# New image is in the wrong place

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to Python and experimenting a bit. So far I managed to load a button in front of a background picture, but if I want to change the background by clicking the button the new picture is in the wrong place, regardless of the set anchor.

```
import tkinter as tk



class App(tk.Tk):



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master.withdraw() # hide second empty window
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.master.destroy) # close program if close button is pressed


        img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Desktop/win10start.png")
        img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Desktop/winButton.png")
        self.c1 = tk.Canvas(master = self, borderwidth = 0, relief = tk.FLAT, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.c1.configure(width = 1024, height = 768)
        self.c1.grid_propagate(False)

        self.c1.create_image((0,0), image = img1, anchor = 'nw')

        b1 = tk.Button(self.c1, image = img2, borderwidth = 0, relief = tk.FLAT, highlightthickness = 0, command = lambda: changeImage(self.c1))
        self.c1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
        b1.place(x = 344, y = 198 )


        self.mainloop()

    def changeImage(canvas):
        newImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Desktop/Koala.png")
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas.configure(width = 1024, height = 768)
        canvas.create_image((0,0), anchor = 'se', image = newImage)
        canvas.image = newImage
        return


App()
```

Is there another way to set the place of a picture which I should use?

Edit:

The code seems to act completely random, as for now after a bit of playing and then restoring the original code the koala is completely gone...I am confused.

[image: newImage]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem does not seem to be about programming but about the strange behaviour of the Spider 3 IDE.

Comment: The koala is completely gone because `newImage` is being garbage-collected at the end of the method, even though it's used in the canvas. Try `self.newImage = ...` instead. Same for the other two images.

Comment: @tobias_k it seems that really helped, thank you! If you create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Wasn't the original problem about the picture being in the wrong place? Is this still a problem with your code, or not?

Comment: @tobias_k No, its quite confusing. Now the picture is where it belongs, I guess maybe because of the garbage collection or something like this the picture wasn't affected by the anchor.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what's going on, that's why I voted to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code.

1 you need to add self as an argument to the `changeImage()` method.

So change:

```
def changeImage(canvas):
```

To:

```
def changeImage(self, canvas):
```

2 you should remove the anchor and change the image location to be higher than 0,0. This will give you an idea of what is going on.

Change:

```
canvas.create_image((0,0), anchor = 'se', image = newImage)
```

To:

```
canvas.create_image((36,36), image = newImage)
```

Your image is being placed it is just being placed out of view. You can play around with the location and the anchor to see whats going on.